# How to get address of member function within the class without using class name for scope?

Tags: c++, class, pointer-to-member

I want to know if it is possible to get the address of a member function within the class without using the class name for scope.

In the below example, inside main is the normal way of getting address, but inside func2, is there a way without using class name. The reason for asking for something like this is, in future if I change the class Name, I don't have to go and change inside.
eg:

```
Class A
{
 void func1()
 {
 }
 void func2()
 {
  /Address of func1/ = &func1; // something like this possible?
 }
}
void main()
{
 /Address of func1/ = &A::func1;
}
```

Comment: Have you ***tried*** it? What happened? What problems (if any) do you get?

Comment: For what purpose would you need to do that at all? What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: `&std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>::func1`. Doesn't seem worth it and doesn't compile for `static` functions due to the lack of `this`.

Comment: in the future if you change the classname you will have to modify other code also (most obvious: constructors), why do you think you need something special for member function pointers? Simply search and replace inside the class definition. I'd rather worry about necessary modifications outside of the class definition

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I am using it while using boost's signals and bind.

Answer (score 7):

For non-`static` member functions,

```
&std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>::func1
```

is one way.

For `static` functions, use `std::addressof`

```
std::addressof(func1);
```

which relies on the fact that the `A::` is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

If `func1` is a `static` function, you can use [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) to get its address.

```
class A
{
    public:
    static void func1()
    {
    }
    void func2()
    {
        auto fptr = std::addressof(func1); 
    }
};
```

**Note:** This will not work on non-`static` member functions.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I checked it out. It seems okay. Don't know why it was DVed. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f8f69ca3527749b

Comment: @Bathsheba: But using `addressof` will not work for non-static functions. Compilation fails with the error:  `invalid use of non-static member function 'void A::func1()'

         auto fptr = std::addressof(func1);`

Comment: Oops. Back in my box.